# Mapping ddrescue and data from a particular head on a hdd

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, clone, ddrescue, head

I'd like to clone data from a particular head of a HDD. Can I do a ddrescue and then divide the rescue image by the number of heads to get multiple images, each with data from one head/surface?

Background: the disk in question (WD Scorpio blue, 320 GB, 2 platters) was opened (in a cleanroom environment) and each platter removed for examination. But the platters may not have been replaced in the right order nor the right way up (don't ask!). I was hoping to perform a ddrescue, split the image into 4 images and try different combinations of concatenations. Or, are the any low level cloning tools (pref Linux) that address the disk using CHS rather than LBA?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, if platters are out of order how will the drive even find the SA?

Comment: And CHS has nothing to do with this, any CHS info the drive publishes is virtual. Drives are addressed by LBA and the drive itself translates these to a particular coordinate on the drive.

Comment: Best place to ask would probably a forum like hddguru.